# setPreviewDisplay vs setPreviewTexture

Tags: android, android-camera

When opening the Android camera, either a SurfaceHolder or an OpenGL SurfaceTexture must be set to hold the displayed images, using `setPreviewDisplay()` (API level 1) or `setPreviewTexture()` (API level 11), respectively.  Is there any difference in speed, device compatibility (aside from API level), or image quality between the two?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Whenever you use `SurfaceView` to open camera, you can see a little lag and blink in screen. This is because, `SurfaceView` creates a new separate window where in `TextureView` (added in API level 14) does not create new window but acts as normal view, so, you won't see any lag or blink while opening camera using `TextureView`.
This is more of a performance issue.

For more information, look [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/TextureView.html).